# Scheduler for sqs listener

Tags: java, amazon-sqs, spring-cloud-aws

I am using @sqslistener annotation based method to read from an aws queue.
I have been successful in setting it up and all the various configurations are working as expected.

Now what I am trying to achieve is that the sqslistener listen to the queue only during a specific period of the day when I am expecting messages in the queue. For example say from 9.00 am to 3.00 pm everyday. So stop listening from 3.00pm to 9.00 am next day and repeat this. 
Is there configuration available to achieve this ?

I have looked at the documentation but I couldn't find anything related to this.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I'm curious: what's the use case behind this?

Comment: Were you able to find a way to achieve this?